# How to check network status using terminal?

Tags: linux

Sometimes my wireless connection becomes `Limited Access` .

Is there anyway to display network status (like connection is Online or Offline or has limited access etc) in terminal ?

Comment: What type of network status are you looking for?

Comment: @Michael for example is connected or not and has limited access or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check firstly if the wireless connection is available with this command:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Then connect to your wireless connection with this command (replace wlan0 with your own network interface if needed):

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

To display WiFi signal strength in the terminal, you can run this command:

```
watch -n 1 "awk 'NR==3 {print \"WiFi Signal Strength = \" \$3 \"00 %\"}''' /proc/net/wireless"
```

[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/display-wifi-signal-strength-in-real.html)